# Move a div within another div with arrow keys

Tags: javascript

I am new in JavaScript, so I have some difficulties with it. I would like to move a small div within another bigger div with arrow keys - left, up, right and down. I have the code below but it does not work properly.

HTML and CSS

```
<div id="rectangle">
    <div id="square"></div>
</div>
#rectangle {
        width: 320px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    #square {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top:0;
    }
```

Javascript

```
var rectangle = document.getElementById("rectangle");
var square = document.getElementById("square");
var currentPositionX = 0;
var currentPositionY = 0;

function moveSquare(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        currentPositionX -= 40;
        square.style.left = currentPositionX + 'px';
        if (currentPositionX <= 0) {
            currentPositionX += 40;
        }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        currentPositionY -= 40;
        square.style.top = currentPositionY + 'px';
        if (currentPositionY <= 0) {
            currentPositionY += 40;
        }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        currentPositionX += 40;
        square.style.left = currentPositionX + 'px';
        if (currentPositionX >= 280) {
            currentPositionX -= 40;
        }
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        currentPositionY += 40;
        square.style.top = currentPositionY + 'px';
        if (currentPositionY >= 160) {
            currentPositionY -= 40;
        }
    }
}
document.onkeydown = moveSquare;
```

Comment: It works just fine, but you have to click inside the larger `div` for it to start working.

Comment: Its working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the code and found that when you are near the borders it's not working properly (Perhaps this was the original question?). On this i tested another simpler solution: I just changed your moveSquare function to only do work when you are inside your bounds (I mean, you shouldn't be always incrementing/decrementing position and then check if you are out of bounds to correct it).

```
   function moveSquare(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            if (currentPositionX > 0) {
                currentPositionX -= 40;
                square.style.left = currentPositionX + 'px';
            }

        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            if (currentPositionY > 0) {
                currentPositionY -= 40;
                square.style.top = currentPositionY + 'px';
            }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            if (currentPositionX < 280) {
                currentPositionX += 40;
                square.style.left = currentPositionX + 'px';
            }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            if (currentPositionY < 160) {
                currentPositionY += 40;
                square.style.top = currentPositionY + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epL4a9Lq/

Please, next time be more specific on your error (i would comment this before answering but i have no reputation yet for that).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If someone can edit my indentation mistake i would thank it!

Comment: Yes, the original question was that, I am sorry about the inaccuracy. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Also remember to mark the answers as accepted when you are done so other people can know that it's solved.